# flutter does't see ios-deploy

Tags: macos, flutter

I installed flutter by official docs. When I did flutter doctor -v I don't get information with :
IOS toolchain as my other(old) mac book.

```
[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 11.2.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.2.1, Build version 11B500
    • ios-deploy 1.9.4
    • CocoaPods version 1.8.3
```

Instead this I get:

```
> [✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.2.1)
>     • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
>     • Xcode 11.2.1, Build version 11B500
>     • CocoaPods version 1.8.4
```

and flutter doesn't see ios-deploy. Which I installed as well.

```
ios-deploy --version
1.10.0-beta.3
```

And as result on my new mac book my project doen't work. I cloned the same git branch on my new macbook and get error after run "flutter build ios --release --no-codesign":

```
8 warnings generated.
=== BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===
ld: targeted OS version does not support use of thread local variables in __ZZN9GMSx_absl18container_internal10RandomSeedEvE7counter for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: I dont think not displaying iOS toolchain instead of Xcode is the issue as mine don't either and seems to be working fine. When you say my project doesn't work, what exactly do you mean? can you post log, error etc?

Answer (score 2):

@Pro You was right, this is not flutter issue. 
Answear:
The issue fixed by changing the Deployment Target from 8.0 to 9.0 in Xcode